# How to Prevent Unwanted Export Combination?

Tags: typescript, rollup

I have set up my project as shown in this Git repository: https://github.com/aeroxy/dts-problem-demo

My goal is to output a lib folder with CommonJS (CJS) modules using TypeScript (tsc) and a special server folder where the `index.js` is bundled by Rollup (UMD) from `/src/server.ts`.

The problem arises when I try to generate TypeScript declaration files (*.d.ts) for my `/src/server.ts` file. By default, TypeScript produces a `server.d.ts` declaration file, but I want it to match the name of the output file, which is `index.js`. To address this, I've employed the `rollup-plugin-dts` to bundle the `index.d.ts` from `/src/server.ts`.

However, I've encountered an issue. When I write my source code as follows:

```
export { Demo };
export type { IFoo };
```

The plugin `rollup-plugin-dts` compiles it to:

```
export { type IFoo, ServerDemo };
```

This is undesirable because export `{ type IFoo, ServerDemo }` is not supported in some older versions of TypeScript projects. How can I turn off this automatic combination and make it compile to the expected:

```
export { Demo };
export type { IFoo };
```

Please note that in `lib/server.d.ts`, where TypeScript compiles based on my tsconfig, it doesn't exhibit the unexpected merging of exports.

Comment: Have you tried setting package dependency typescript version to that version?

Comment: @Dimava what do u mean? can u submit a PR to the github repo provided in the question?

Comment: "is not supported in some older versions of TypeScript projects" implies "in older TS version", and I'd expect `rollup-plugin-dts` make types compatible with ts@4 when you use ts@4 as a devDepemdency

Comment: Also try `isolatedModules` docs say smth about it

Comment: @Dimava i see what u meant. unfortunately this is not helpful because the ts version must be 5 to match the rest of the workspace. some of our users still have ts 4, it doesn't make sense to lower our version to resolve this issue. what we want is to allow compiling the project to support lower versions of ts, instead of lowering the project's ts version.

Comment: i have tried isolatedModules and it did not optimize the result